# How can I install Rust using rustup on Windows when behind a firewall?

Tags: proxy, rust

I [downloaded rustup-init.exe](https://rustup.rs/). When I ran it at home, everything went fine, but when I run it from my office through a proxy, I ran into a problem:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc'
error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to 'C:\Users\350627\.rustup\tmp\l3ogei4e89gnb1df_file
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Couldn't resolve host 'static.rust-lang.org')
```

I am on Windows and the `http_proxy` environment variable is properly set.

I tried to "customize installation", but it did not give me the option to manually provide an IP address:

```
1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: I suggest using a [standalone installer](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/other-installers.html#standalone). That's what I do at work.

Comment: Can you resolve `static.rust-lang.org` through other means? A web browser or a command line tool like `dig`?

Comment: @Shepmaster, I can, but the installer is just one single .exe binary and gives no option to configure/take in the solved IP address.

Comment: @ljedrz, perfect! thanks!

Comment: Can you modify your [hosts file](https://superuser.com/questions/47716/how-do-i-block-certain-websites-from-being-accessed-through-a-browser/47720#47720) to hard code the DNS response?

Comment: @kennytm, good idea, tested and worked. I will add this to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

I followed aSpex's advice...

1. Go to https://www.rust-lang.org/ -> Install
2. Download rustup-init.exe to ~/Downloads
3. In powershell:

   ```
   $proxy='http://<IP>:<PORT>'

   $ENV:HTTP_PROXY=$proxy 
   $ENV:HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy
   cd ~\Downloads
   .\rustup-init.exe
   ```

Comment: This is super useful for other applications too. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP who has stated their `http_proxy` environment variable is already set.

Comment: This will not work when the corporate proxy is a url with a path, not a port.

Comment: If you have auth required set: $proxy='http://<UserName>:<Password>@<IP>:<PORT>'

Answer (score 7):

I have tested two solutions that were suggested as comments above, and both worked. Thanks, kennytm and ljedrz!

1. Suggested by kennytm, add the following line to the hosts file in c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

   13.32.244.72    static.rust-lang.org
2. Suggested by ljedrz, use a standalone installer. In the past, one could easily find those standalone installers, but with the latest reorg of the rust language site, the only thing really pops out initially is the rustup-init.exe. However as @ljedrz pointed out in his comment above, those standalone installers still exist and can be found here: [standalone installers for various platforms](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/other-installers.html#standalone).

Comment: Have you tried to set up environment variable `https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port`? After that rustup started working for me.

Comment: 1 didn't work but 2 did. I guess I really have a problem with my proxy at the office (http(s)_proxy environment variable seems ignored, so I can't use Package Control on Sublime Text, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I used a slightly different set of variables. The following is bash on Windows:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=c:/wherever/bundle.crt
export RUSTUP_USE_REQWEST=1
export http_proxy=http://yourproxy:port
export https_proxy=http:// yourproxy:port
rustup update
```

You'll need to adjust the path to the certificate appropriately for your company.

I used this tool to detect the proxy, but you can use any tool to get the URL:

https://github.com/aellerton/proxyhelper

Answer (score 0):

My rustup was not using curl and the https_proxy variable needed modification.

1. Enabling curl for rustup:

   set RUSTUP_USE_CURL=1
2. Remove the protocol in the value for https_proxy

   set https_proxy=user:passwd@host:port
3. retry

   rustup install stable

   rustup default stable

The information was gleaned from: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/network-proxies.html